# Get email with Facebook Firebase Simple Login

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-plus, firebasesimplelogin

I am using Facebook with Firebase Simple Login. I am trying to get the person's real name, which I have successfully done via `user.displayName` in my FirebaseSimpleLogin instance. When I try getting their email with `user.email`, it returns `undefined`. I have done the same thing with Google+ and it works just fine, no undefineds returned. Here is my code:

```
var chatRef = new Firebase('https://******.firebaseio.com');
//No, i didn't actually put this firebase name in my code =P
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    // an error occurred while attempting login
    console.log(error);
    alert('An error occurred while trying to log you in.' + error);
  } else if (user) {
    // user authenticated with Firebase
    console.log('Name: ' + user.displayName + ', email: ' + user.email);
    //With google, 'Name: John Doe, email: johndoe@example.com' is returned
    //With facebook, 'Name: John Doe, email: undefined' is returned
  } else {
    // user is logged out
  }


});

function google() {
  auth.login('google', {
    rememberMe: true
  });
}

function facebook() {
  auth.login('facebook', {
    rememberMe: true,
    scope: 'email'
  });
}
```

So, my question is, how can i get the user's email address with Facebook Firebase Simple Login? Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: In addition to what I posted in my answer, if you add to the code:  `else if (user) { console.log(user);}`  you'll know what properties exist on the user object as you have it set up currently. Additional permission might be required - see below. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you start, the best way to see what properties already exist on the user object is to add a console log to your existing auth check.

Using:

```
else if (user){
  console.log(user);
}
```

you'll know what properties exist on the user object as you have it set up currently. Additional permission might be required - see below.

Per [facebook dev docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#permissions), permissions are strings that are passed along with a login request or an API call. Here are two examples of permissions:

- email: Access to a person's primary email address.
- user_likes: Access to the list of things a person likes.

For example, if you add the login button to a web app and ask for email and user_likes via the scope parameter, a person would be prompted with this dialog when logging in for the first time:

And per [firebase Docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-facebook.html)

Here is an example where the session will be stored for 30 days (due to the 'remember me' setting), and we also request some extended permissions for email and user_likes:

```
auth.login('facebook', {
  rememberMe: true,
  scope: 'email,user_likes'
});
```

So, unless you have added the additional permissions in the auth.login parameters, you will not be able to access the user's primary email address.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on logging `user` in the console. I found one property `thirdPartyUserData` which contains the user's primary email address. I retrieved it using `user.thirdPartyUserData.email`

Comment: Agreed with `scope: 'email'` is needed. I find that now email is stored depending on the provider. Either in `user.google.email`, `user.facebook.email`, `user.password.email`. The middle property is stored in `user.provider`. So I generically get the email address using: `user[user.provider].email`.